# Validate an Enum with char values

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum of this type

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Private = '1',
    Public = '2',
    Manual = '3'
}
```

The database stores values for MyEnum as "1", "2", "3" as a string.

I am trying unsuccessfully to write some code that given an input string value, will return me the matching Enum, like:

```
var inputString = '2';
MyEnum result = ConvertStringToMyEnum(inputString);
```

In case the inputString is not valid, throw an exception or let me know somehow that is not a valid value.

Comment: You are writing code but you don't show it, what is `ConvertStringToMyEnum`?

Comment: I see there are a lot of "answers" already, but I'll ask anyway ... why don't you store those values as an integer in your DB?

Comment: Thanks all guys, I think you have all resolved my issue! thanks a lot

Comment: @IMR Don't forget to vote on answers that help and, if you feel you have a good solution, then you can also accept an answer too.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast a char to your enum like this:

```
var enumValue = (MyEnum)"2"[0];
```

And to check it's a valid enum value:

```
var isValid = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), enumValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T ToEnum< T >(string @string)   
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@string))
   {
    throw new ArgumentException("Argument null or empty");
   }
   if (@string.Length > 1)
   {
    throw new ArgumentException("Argument length greater than one");
   }
   return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), @string[0]);
}
```

More can be found here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78600/C-Enum-with-Char-Valued-Items

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Enum` to obtain all valid values: string `value` is *valid* if and only if

```
1. `value` is of length `1`
2. `MyEnum` declares `value[0]` as valid value
```

Implementation:

```
string value = "1";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) &&
     value.Length == 1 && 
     Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<int>().Any(item => item == value[0])) {
  Console.WriteLine("Valid");
}
```

**Edit:** If you have *many* a `value` to check, cache the valid ones:

```
static HashSet<int> s_Valids = new HashSet<int>(Enum
  .GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
  .Cast<int>());

...

string value = "1";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) &&
     value.Length == 1 && 
     s_Valids.Contains(value[0])) {
  Console.WriteLine("Valid");
}
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of work though as you need to enumerate the entire enum, seems excessive and wasteful to me.

Comment: Even with the edit, you're still generating a pointless collection here. `Enum.IsDefined` already does this work for you, there's no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You neet to parse first:

```
var returnValue = MyEnum.Default;

if (int.TryParse(dbString), out int intValue)
{
    returnValue = (MyEnum)intValue;
}

return returnValue
```

For pre-C#6

```
var returnValue = MyEnum.Default;

int intValue;
if (int.TryParse(dbString), out intValue)
{
    returnValue = (MyEnum)intValue;
}

return returnValue
```